# sf::Clock sends out random words for time

Tags: c++, sfml

I was trying to create a rate limiter in sfml but it wasn't working properly so I tried to print out the time,

and this was the result.

> 3e-06

and my code is

```
int main()
{
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time time = clock.getElapsedTime();

    while(true) std::cout << time.asSeconds() << std::endl;
}
```

So I was wondering if I really needed sf::RenderWindow or something or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Clock.php#abe889b42a65bcd8eefc16419645d08a7) for `getElapsedTime` states (emphasis mine):

> This function returns the time elapsed since the last call to restart() **(or the construction of the instance if restart() has not been called)**.

So, in other words, you are measuring the elapsed time between:

```
sf::Clock clock;
```

and:

```
sf::Time time = clock.getElapsedTime();
```

for which 3 microseconds seems not unreasonable.

You probably meant to put the call to `clock.getElapsedTime` inside your loop.